# Are there mechanisms preventing DeviceCheck timestamps from acting as fingerprints?

Tags: ios, ios11, fingerprint, privacy, fingerprinting

iOS 11 adds DeviceCheck, a mechanism to allow app developers to store a small amount of data (2 bits, along with a timestamp) that stays on the device, surviving deletion of the app. This is mean to identify for example, if a user has already participated in a free trial, or other similar purposes, while preventing a unique identification (fingerprinting) of the user. [Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck)

My question is couldn’t this theoretically be abused by developers to store much more data (potentially uniquely fingerprinting the user), by using a unique timestamp? Is there any mechanism keeping developers from doing this? If not this could be a significant privacy concern, defeating the point of this feature.

I could easily see malicious developers either storing the timestamp on their server to later uniquely identify the user, or simply waiting to store the data until a particular timestamp arrives, and encoding data in (the lower few bits of) the timestamp itself. Is this an actual risk?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_per_device_data) it looks like the `last_update_time` timestamp that Apple gives you is in the `YYYY-MM` format. If you have more than a handful of users it's probably safe to assume that month-level granularity on the timestamp isn't enough to uniquely identify any user.